# Adding element at a particular index in a multi-dimensional array in ruby

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

When I attempt the `.insert(index,element)` logic with multi dimensional array:

```
expected_array[row][col].insert(1,score.to_s.concat("%"))
```

in the loop of each row where score =73 ,

I get output as:

```
["M73%axi's", 25, "03/06/2012"]
```

when my expected result has to be:

```
["Maxi's", "73%", 25, "03/06/2012"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You have a bidimensional array there and what `expected_array[row][col]` does is get to a specific element. So that you are calling `String#insert` (of the element) instead of `Array#insert` (of the inner array).

What you want instead is to select the row and call `Array#insert` on the column array:

```
expected_array[row].insert(col,score.to_s.concat("%"))
```